# Excluding files from ant build in javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

So here i am with yet another javadoc question: Here is my stuff
[code]

```
<delete dir="${build.dir}" />

<delete dir="${docs.dir}" />

<delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
```

```
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />

<mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />

<mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
```

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">

</javac>
```

```
<javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">

  <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->

   <fileset dir="${src.dir}">

            <include name="**" />

       </fileset>

</javadoc>
```

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}\driver.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">

  <manifest>

    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="driver.Driver" />

  </manifest>

</jar>
```

```
<description>run the program</description>

<java jar="${dist.dir}/driver.jar" fork="true">

  <!-- if you needed arguments -->

  <!--

  <arg value="${args0}" />

  <arg value="${args1}" />

  -->

</java>
```

```
<description>Main target</description>
```

now my src folder has files known as `input1.txt`, `input2.txt`, `input3.txt`, and when im generating docs, i get this error:

```
[javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: blablabla/input1.txt
```

I tried using the `excludes` command but it says javadoc doesn't support that. Is there a way i can exclude files with a `.txt` ending from being trying to made javadocs off of?

I am pretty new to ant so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `excludes` attribute in `<fileset>` or several `<exclude name="..." />` nested in `<fileset>` to exclude certain files from the fileset that will be sent to javadoc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But see i am not trying to exclude certain files, im trying to exclude an entire extension. Our professor, rather than putting "input1.txt", could put"bla.txt" for the main file input, and then it would throw an error. Is it not possible to exclude an entire file extension?

Comment: Yes. You can use wildcards: `**/*.txt` means all files ending in `txt` in any subdirectory below the fileset directory root.

Comment: so since i want it to exclude all .txt files in the src directory, do i do <exclude name="${src}/*.txt/>?? If thats not the case, would you mind posting the correct code? Would be much appreciated :) And would i need to to put this in the target name compile or target name doc?

Comment: `<exclude name="**/*.txt>`. The directory you already informed in the `dir` attribute of the `<fileset>` where you places the `<exclude>`

Comment: I am sorry, i am REALLY new to ant, this was basically a model build file provided copy and pasted from the one provided by the professor. I did not understand where i am suppose to put that exclude name="**/.txt>. Would you be able to explain the specific place. Much thanks :)

Comment: `<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
    <include name="**/*" />
    <exclude name="**/*.txt" />
</fileset>`

Comment: THANK YOU. THat solved my problem :). I wish i had enough reputation to upvote your answer. Thank you once againn :D